# Ordering SQL results by the field where they are found

Tags: mysql, sql

We have a search query that allows the users to enter a string and then searches 3 separate fields via LIKE '%string%'. The fields are:

- Name
- Description
- Type

When then return the results and right now just order them arbitrarily. We would prefer the results be ordered first by results found in the Name field, second by items found in the Description field, and then lastly in the Type field. Because we have paging and sorting also associated with this, we really want it returned in one record set. Is this even possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: MSSQL, MySQL, Oracle? How does the query look like? What have you tried so far?

Comment: it is MySQL, right now it looks like the one below except I am just ordering by name. Select * from Table where Name like '%string%' and description like '%string%' and type like '%string%' order by name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, the following should work:

```
SELECT *
FROM atable
WHERE Name        LIKE '%string%'
   OR Description LIKE '%string%'
   OR Type        LIKE '%string%'
ORDER BY
   CASE
     WHEN Name        LIKE '%string%' THEN 1
     WHEN Description LIKE '%string%' THEN 2
     WHEN Type        LIKE '%string%' THEN 3
   END
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Select * 
from Tablename 
where Name like '%string%' 
and description like '%string%' 
and type like '%string%' 
order by name,description,type
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this :

```
Select * 
from Table 
where Name like '%string%' 
and description like '%string%' 
and type like '%string%' 
order by name,description,type
```

Comment: Hmm that doesn't seem to return them in the right order because if it finds it in a description and the description has a name that is higher alphabetically than the "name" it matches, then it shows it first. I want the name results to actually appear prior... may have to do some post sorting on it.